# How to add space between names in string PHP?

Tags: php, whitespace

I'm a student and I'm learning PHP. I have a very long list of names but they are in 1 piece.

Example:

```
$names = "NathanaelDousaMaxbergenRafaelSteen";
```

Is there a way to put space between the names?

Is there a function for that?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are still learning, why not go through the manual and find out what kind of functions there are? https://php.net/manual/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `preg_replace` here:

```
$names = "NathanaelDousaMaxbergenRafaelSteen";
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/", " ", $names);
echo $output;  // Nathanael Dousa Maxbergen Rafael Steen
```

The regex pattern `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` will match every position which is preceded by a lowercase letter and followed by an uppercase letter.  It replaces with a single space, effectively adding a space before the start of each name.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be a regular expression, which is a little advanced.

#### Using `preg_replace()`

Here is an example solution with a regular expression:

```php
$string = "NathanaelDousaMaxbergenRafaelSteen";
echo preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1 $2', $string);
```

The above searches a lower case letter, followed by a capital letter and puts a space between them.
You can play around with this regular expression here (also check the right side for an in-depth explanation):
https://regex101.com/r/cvltMB/1

#### But please, also learn for yourself

I recommend going to the official manual:
https://php.net/manual/

Visit there everything you need a function for something - it is likely there already or can be combination of several. The comments also help for common tricks and pitfalls.
There is also information about regular expressions. It is a large topic, but good to know. Once you've learned it you will always come back to it.

You can also achieve similar with [strtr()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtr.php), which would be more code to write but also a valid example of just getting to an answer.

Especially learning PHP - just read the manual and see what kind of functions are available. There is a whole section for text manipulation which might inspire you to your own solution. You might get corrected on *the best way* or whatever, but especially learning there is no wrong way but copying your solution from others.